# In Android OpenCV Color Blob Detector is crashing by giving fatal error

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.1

I'm using Color Blob detector Sample code of OpenCV ([Sample Code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection)), but app is crashing at `Core.multiply(contour, new Scalar(4,4), contour);` giving some fatal error

> libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 11016 (Thread-4857)

and detailed Log is available to get idea of exact reason. In some other part of code I was using `Core.add(fg, bg, markers);` and app was giving same fatal error there as well. What is the issue? Please guide towards the solution. I 'm using openCV(3.1)
Code is as following:

```
    package com.iu.kamraapp.utils;

import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class ColorBlobDetector {
    // Lower and Upper bounds for range checking in HSV color space
    private Scalar mLowerBound = new Scalar(0);
    private Scalar mUpperBound = new Scalar(0);
    // Minimum contour area in percent for contours filtering
    private static double mMinContourArea = 0.1;
    // Color radius for range checking in HSV color space
    private Scalar mColorRadius = new Scalar(25,50,50,0);
    private Mat mSpectrum = new Mat();
    private List<MatOfPoint> mContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

    // Cache
    Mat mPyrDownMat = new Mat();
    Mat mHsvMat = new Mat();
    Mat mMask = new Mat();
    Mat mDilatedMask = new Mat();
    Mat mHierarchy = new Mat();

    public void setColorRadius(Scalar radius) {
        mColorRadius = radius;
    }

    public void setHsvColor(Scalar hsvColor) {
        double minH = (hsvColor.val[0] >= mColorRadius.val[0]) ? hsvColor.val[0]-mColorRadius.val[0] : 0;
        double maxH = (hsvColor.val[0]+mColorRadius.val[0] <= 255) ? hsvColor.val[0]+mColorRadius.val[0] : 255;

        mLowerBound.val[0] = minH;
        mUpperBound.val[0] = maxH;

        mLowerBound.val[1] = hsvColor.val[1] - mColorRadius.val[1];
        mUpperBound.val[1] = hsvColor.val[1] + mColorRadius.val[1];

        mLowerBound.val[2] = hsvColor.val[2] - mColorRadius.val[2];
        mUpperBound.val[2] = hsvColor.val[2] + mColorRadius.val[2];

        mLowerBound.val[3] = 0;
        mUpperBound.val[3] = 255;

        Mat spectrumHsv = new Mat(1, (int)(maxH-minH), CvType.CV_8UC3);

        for (int j = 0; j < maxH-minH; j++) {
            byte[] tmp = {(byte)(minH+j), (byte)255, (byte)255};
            spectrumHsv.put(0, j, tmp);
        }

        Imgproc.cvtColor(spectrumHsv, mSpectrum, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL, 4);
    }

    public Mat getSpectrum() {
        return mSpectrum;
    }

    public void setMinContourArea(double area) {
        mMinContourArea = area;
    }

    public void process(Mat rgbaImage) {
        try {
            Imgproc.pyrDown(rgbaImage, mPyrDownMat);
            Imgproc.pyrDown(mPyrDownMat, mPyrDownMat);


            Imgproc.cvtColor(mPyrDownMat, mHsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);

            Core.inRange(mHsvMat, mLowerBound, mUpperBound, mMask);
            Imgproc.dilate(mMask, mDilatedMask, new Mat());

            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

            Imgproc.findContours(mDilatedMask, contours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            // Find max contour area
            double maxArea = 0;
            Iterator<MatOfPoint> each = contours.iterator();
            while (each.hasNext()) {
                MatOfPoint wrapper = each.next();
                double area = Imgproc.contourArea(wrapper);
                if (area > maxArea)
                    maxArea = area;
            }

            // Filter contours by area and resize to fit the original image size
            mContours.clear();

            each = contours.iterator();
            while (each.hasNext()) {
                MatOfPoint contour = each.next();
                if (Imgproc.contourArea(contour) > mMinContourArea * maxArea) {

                    Core.multiply(contour, new Scalar(4, 4), contour);   // issue is here
                    mContours.add(contour);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {  e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public List<MatOfPoint> getContours() {
        return mContours;
    }
}

package com.iu.kamraapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

import com.iu.kamraapp.utils.AppGlobal;
import com.iu.kamraapp.utils.ColorBlobDetector;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ColorBlobActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener,CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Context context;
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private boolean              mIsColorSelected = false;
    private Mat                  mRgba;
    private Scalar               mBlobColorRgba;
    private Scalar               mBlobColorHsv;
    private ColorBlobDetector mDetector;
    private Mat                  mSpectrum;
    private Size SPECTRUM_SIZE;
    private Scalar               CONTOUR_COLOR;

    BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {

        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                    mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(ColorBlobActivity.this);
                }
                break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        screenWidth = AppGlobal.getScreenResolution(context, true);
        screenHeight = AppGlobal.getScreenResolution(context, false);
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            screenWidth = AppGlobal.getScreenResolution(context, false);
            screenHeight = AppGlobal.getScreenResolution(context, true);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            screenWidth = AppGlobal.getScreenResolution(context, true);
            screenHeight = AppGlobal.getScreenResolution(context, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
            OpenCVLoader.initDebug(true);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mDetector = new ColorBlobDetector();
        mSpectrum = new Mat();
        mBlobColorRgba = new Scalar(255);
        mBlobColorHsv = new Scalar(255);
        SPECTRUM_SIZE = new Size(200, 64);
        CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255,0,0,255);
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       try {
           int cols = mRgba.cols();
           int rows = mRgba.rows();

           int xOffset = (mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth() - cols) / 2;
           int yOffset = (mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight() - rows) / 2;

           int x = (int) event.getX() - xOffset;
           int y = (int) event.getY() - yOffset;

           Log.i(TAG, "Touch image coordinates: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

           if ((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x > cols) || (y > rows)) return false;

           Rect touchedRect = new Rect();

           touchedRect.x = (x > 4) ? x - 4 : 0;
           touchedRect.y = (y > 4) ? y - 4 : 0;

           touchedRect.width = (x + 4 < cols) ? x + 4 - touchedRect.x : cols - touchedRect.x;
           touchedRect.height = (y + 4 < rows) ? y + 4 - touchedRect.y : rows - touchedRect.y;

           Mat touchedRegionRgba = mRgba.submat(touchedRect);

           Mat touchedRegionHsv = new Mat();
           Imgproc.cvtColor(touchedRegionRgba, touchedRegionHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);


           // Calculate average color of touched region
           mBlobColorHsv = Core.sumElems(touchedRegionHsv);
           int pointCount = touchedRect.width * touchedRect.height;
           for (int i = 0; i < mBlobColorHsv.val.length; i++)
               mBlobColorHsv.val[i] /= pointCount;


           mBlobColorRgba = converScalarHsv2Rgba(mBlobColorHsv);

           Log.i(TAG, "Touched rgba color: (" + mBlobColorRgba.val[0] + ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[1] +
                   ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[2] + ", " + mBlobColorRgba.val[3] + ")");


           mDetector.setHsvColor(mBlobColorHsv);


           Imgproc.resize(mDetector.getSpectrum(), mSpectrum, SPECTRUM_SIZE);

           mIsColorSelected = true;

           touchedRegionRgba.release();
           touchedRegionHsv.release();
       } catch (Exception e)  { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return false; // don't need subsequent touch events
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        if (mIsColorSelected) {
            mDetector.process(mRgba);
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
            Log.d(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());
            Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR);

            Mat colorLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 68, 4, 68);
            colorLabel.setTo(mBlobColorRgba);

            Mat spectrumLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 4 + mSpectrum.rows(), 70, 70 + mSpectrum.cols());
            mSpectrum.copyTo(spectrumLabel);
        }

        return mRgba;
    }

    private Scalar converScalarHsv2Rgba(Scalar hsvColor) {
        Mat pointMatRgba = new Mat();
        Mat pointMatHsv = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, hsvColor);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(pointMatHsv, pointMatRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL, 4);

        return new Scalar(pointMatRgba.get(0, 0));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code into the answer. See how to do a [mcve]

Comment: @Miki I've added the link of code . Issue is in this file at the mentioned line https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetector.java

Comment: Yeah, I can see that you put a link to your code, but that's not ok for stackoverflow. Please re-read my previous comment

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39833284/6305235).

Comment: all other commands are running, when i comment the above mentioned line then app runs without crash. But skipping that line doesn't complete the algo.

Comment: @Usman Are you using OpenCV Manager from the Play Store?

Comment: Yes @David, I was using it from Playstore, but manual installation (as you said) worked for me. Thanks